# Fontawesome not loading

Tags: css, apache, mime-types, font-awesome

I'm currently using Fotawesome at a project. The problem is, that when I load the webpage, I only see blocks instead of icons. The fonts 'can't be found on the server', but I'm sure they are at the right location (I can browse to the files myself). When I load the webpage with localhost, everything works fine. Fontawesome is NOT installed on my computer. Could it be that is has something to do with mimetypes? How do I fix this? (I'm using an apache server)

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: The font isn't being loaded. Make sure your paths are correct.

Comment: In case anyone was stuck (not carefully reading the docs) like me: the font-family is loaded on the .fa class. If you, as I did, have `class="fa-phone"` you will not load the font. You need `class="fa fa-phone"` to load the font.

Comment: and don't be confused like me thinking fa = fa-fw. I needed to have class = "fa fa-fw fa-phone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the path to Font Awesome is relative to where the CSS is stored (if you're using relative paths).

Also, if it's an option, Bootstrap CDN makes it really easy to use Font Awesome:
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=01042013155511#tab_fontawesome

Comment: I tried including the relative path only for font-awesome.min.css placed in my css folder .Also i tried the source that u have mentioned above. Still its not working for me .