# Font-Awesome icons not rendering via the BoostrapCDN

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font-Awesome icon fonts via the BootstrapCDN link which I'm pretty sure I have the latest version of:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've put this link in the `<head>` part of my html file and I am trying to get it to work with this simple html code of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Font-Awesome Icons</title> 
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Camera Icon<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook Icon</p>
</body>
</html>
```

However it's not rendering.  I've tried this code in the latest versions of FireFox (27), Safari(7) and Chrome(33).  I've checked that the `fa` class is on each of the icons I'm trying to call up and also that the `fa-` prefix is being used as opposed to the old `icon-` prefix.  I've checked my implementation of the code with this video http://headwaythemes.com/using-font-awesome-with-headway/ (although meant for a WordPress theme, in principal the code should work the same) and looked around on stack overflow but previous questions like [Fontawesome not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527734/fontawesome-not-loading) haven't yielded me any help in solving my issue.

I don't have the fontawesome.otf installed but surely it isn't that if I can see the glyphs when visiting http://fortawesome.github.io.
Should I just download and host the font-awesome files along with my entire future website so I don't have to worry about updating the BoostrapCDN link as well? - Even though I only plan to use a few icons?

Comment: seems to work fine for me check your connection 

http://jsfiddle.net/qK2r2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is not loading is because the URI is starting with "//".  That signifies that it is a protocol relative path, meaning it will use whatever protocol that page is using. If you open your html locally, then your browser will use *file* as the protocol, thus trying to access the font-awesome css with "file://".  If you access your html using a local or remote http web server, then you would access the page using the *http* protocol, thus accessing the css with "http://".

**Solution:**

1. Change the path of the css or mimic it on your local machine.
2. Run a local or remote http server and access the page.

For more info:
[URI starting with two slashes ... how do they behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave)

Comment: Thank you Pulkit.  I moved my files over to a MAMP stack local web server which allowed it to pull the glyphs from the CDN correctly in all the browsers now.  I also checked by adding the `http:` in front of the `//` outside of the local web server which also allowed it to reach the CDN so it was definitely that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Such an easier way to deal with this - just add 'http:' in front for the cdn line, and it will work on your local machine, i.e. like this:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ta-daa!

Answer (score 0):

What Pulkit answered is absolutely correct. Just to add, if you want to create a quick local server, just go to the directory of the html and css pages, and then go to the terminal and type -

$python -m SimpleHTTPServer

Then, go to your browser and go to 127.0.0.1:8000
If it doesn't show up, try changing the homepage of your website to index.html