# Font Awesome Showing Box instead of Icons

Tags: css, html, fonts

I've imported all the font awesome css into my website using the following link code:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link href="content/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="content/css/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="content/css/WDWStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And then added the icons using:

```
<p>Find me at:</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Twitter</a> 
<a class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-github"></span> Github</a>     
<a class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span> Linked in</a>
```

My custom CSS is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'headline_onehplhs';
    src: url('fonts/HEADOH__-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/HEADOH__-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/HEADOH__-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/HEADOH__-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/HEADOH__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/HEADOH__-webfont.svg#headline_onehplhs') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body {
  background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.heading {
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-family: 'headline_onehplhs';
    font-size:3.5em;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding:20px;
    color:#000;
}

.heading span, .main span {
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-family: 'headline_onehplhs';
    color:#999;
    font-size:0.5em;
    display:block;
}

.main span {
    font-size:1.75em;
}

.main {
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

My directory is laid out as follows:

css > font-awesome > [font awesome folders]

And the container that I'm using has the class name "main"

But the icons still display as square boxes - is there something I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font-Awesome icons not rendering via the BoostrapCDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002238/font-awesome-icons-not-rendering-via-the-boostrapcdn)

Comment: What about your CSS to assign the font? something like fa {font-family:}

Comment: This isn't an answer.... but I would suggest you start using svg sprites. The icon fonts are finicky in general. fontastic.me is pretty great...

Comment: Why you need cdn along with font-awesome css that you have on your directories ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/

Comment: Try to use <i class="fa fa-twitter"> rather than <span class="fa fa-twitter"> I found it's odd <span> won't work sometimes.

Comment: Works! Thanks - if you post that as an asnwer I'll check it off as the right answer ;) - thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `<i class="fa fa-twitter">` rather than `<span class="fa fa-twitter">`

On the official doc:

> After you get up and running, you can place Font Awesome icons just
>   about anywhere with the `<i>` tag.

It also says:

> You can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere using the CSS
>   Prefix `fa` and the icon's name. Font Awesome is designed to be used
>   with inline elements (we like the `<i>` tag for brevity, but using a
>   `<span>` is more semantically correct).

Although it sounds like using `<span>` is also acceptable, but it does not work correctly in some cases, so stay with `<i>` is a safer plan.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

If that fixes your problem, then you either didn't upload the fonts in the correct directory or you are referencing them incorrectly.

Here is a test showing the minimum code required to use font awesome:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, something is blocking your connection.  Are you using any sort of adblockers or extra security settings on your browser?  Try using the CDN on a different browser.

Comment: I'm running this on Firefox and all I have additionally is a few Web Dev plug-ins - tried on a different browser (Chrome) which is standard, and still I get the same issue

Comment: Check my edit to the answer.  Can you see the camera icons in the example?

Comment: If you can see it, then something else other than the code you've shown us is the issue.

Comment: I'll edit the question and post any relevant CSS to that page/section as that's the only thing I can think I have left that could be getting in the way

Comment: My guess is that it's something to do with your environment.  If you can copy paste the code I have above, remove all of your custom CSS and it doesn't work for you, it is something beyond your code.  Possibly something on your browser, OS, or network level.

Answer (score 1):

Noone has mentioned the font folder in relation to the fonts. Think like why in you have to put ../ in front of background image to let it know that the img Is not contained in the CSS folder. Check the font-awesome.css file and see where it Is referencing the fonts.

Comment: The Font Awesome CSS is referencing the fonts like this:

src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');

and the folder structure is Root > Content > Css > font-awesome > [font awesome folders]

My css is in the Content > CSS folder

Comment: God bless you! I had wrong path (folder name) in my fontawesome.min.css file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

HTML link

```
<link href='content/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css?family=font+awesome' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

CSS

```
fa{
   font-family: 'font awesome';
  }
```

Source: similar use 
http://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse

Answer (score 1):

in AspNetCore (.net 7), I had this problem showing a box instead of the fontawesome icon.  I'm using NPM to gulp the package and copy to wwwroot/css/fontawesome.  After adding the correct links to the _Hosts.cshtml everything looks good.

```
<link href="/css/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In development mode, I noticed 404 on the webfont files.  After more research, I found that the mime types were not configured properly.  Adding the following to program.cs, the problem is solved:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); //Existing

// Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
// Add new mappings
provider.Mappings[".ttf"] = "font/ttf";
provider.Mappings[".woff"] = "font/woff";
provider.Mappings[".woff2"] = "font/woff2";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});


app.UseRouting(); //Existing
```

Comment: Thanks.  Had the same problem.  Needed to include both fontawesome.min.css AND solid.min.css.