# CSS content property is displaying a box character in chrome console.log, why not text?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, console, font-face

I am now working with custom icon font that I made. Just trying something I got this. I have my style-sheet file in which all my fonts with their respective content property and its value like,`.assassin_creed:before {content: "\e018";}`

Seeing this class in chrome console it gives me back something like `.assassin_creed::before {content: "";}`
Why am I getting this box instead of the content value? How can I be able to retrieve its value in text in chrome console ??

[image: Here's the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Its a invalid `escaped unicode` string, so its showing the Box thats even box will be displayed, if you use Chinese fonts which is not loaded in your browser.

Access Property Value in JS:

```
 var assassin_creed = document.querySelector('.assassin_creed'), 
      result   = getComputedStyle(assassin_creed, ':before').content;

  console.log('the generated content is: ', result); // returns '\e018'
```

Try like below to understand better:

```
.assassin_creed:before {
  content: '>\0000a0';
}
```

Similar Question: [Font Awesome Showing Box instead of Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331137/font-awesome-showing-box-instead-of-icons)

**Refer Content CSS Property to understand better:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before
[Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

Comment: But Anna, the custom font I made which contains Assassins Creed icon is rendered perfectly in all (chrome, ie, firefox, opera) browsers. The code displays the icon perfectly on the page. I have to retrieve its content value using javascript so that further action can be taken. To proceed further I have to get the value in text format like "\e018", not like the displayed box in image above, so how would I be able to retrieve its value in text format using javascript..??